# Add points to shapefile and display over map interactively using Python Add-Ins

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, python-addin

I want to add points to a shapefile interactively using pythonaddins and display them over map. Points are added to shapefile but not to display. Please suggest how to fix this discrepancy.

```
class AddPoints(object):
   """Implementation for points_addin.tool1 (Tool)"""
   def __init__(self):
       self.enabled = False
       self.shape = 3

   def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
       xy = (x,y)
       cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r'C:/temp/points.shp', ("SHAPE@XY"))
       cursor.insertRow([xy])

       arcpy.RefreshTOC()
       arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: Do they show after refresh manually or next time opening?

Comment: Wait, it worked. I restarted my machine and now it is displaying points :)

Comment: Were there any points in there to start with? Odd things can happen with new feature class when you first add feature, it has to do with the extent starting from nothing and becoming something, sometimes the feature is not picked up.

Comment: A new shapefile is created every time before running above tool. Points are then added. It was somehow storing the points whenever I clicked on map but was not displaying it.

Comment: I think you might need to delete the cursor to flush it. This releases locks also. Perhaps a *with* statement would solve it, otherwise *del cursor* before *arcpy.RefreshTOC()*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an insert cursor the inserted object *may not* be written to the feature class as soon as you call `insertRow`, Python is based on C and C uses filestream objects with windows buffering and aren't flushed until the `OFstream::flush();` is called.. this means little from the Python point of view but still needs to be understood. It is best to dismiss the cursor, which will call the flush in its destructor.

Two methods can be used for this, first the `with` method (see [Python with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)):

```
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    xy = (x,y)
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r'C:/temp/points.shp', ("SHAPE@XY")) as cursor:
        cursor.insertRow([xy])
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

the older (to me anyway) method is the `del` statement (see [Python del](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146963/when-is-del-useful-in-python)):

```
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
   xy = (x,y)
   cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r'C:/temp/points.shp', ("SHAPE@XY"))
   cursor.insertRow([xy])
   del cursor

   arcpy.RefreshTOC()
   arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Either way will force your point to show and update the extent of the shapefile.